# Select similar records from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a database as shown below

```
ID    color number          code
102966  red 1   9f6606069f9b999b
102968  red 1   9f6606069f9b999b
102967  red 1   9f0606069f9f9f9f
102969  red 1   9f0606069f9f9f9f
103630  red 1   bbff9f0f8fdc9f7e
101582  red 1   bbff9b0fcf9f99d9
102000  red 1   99fd9f0fab999fff
101603  red 1   bbff9f0d8f9d96df
102016  red 1   bbff9900c09999df
```

This table has more then 4000 entries. 
I got this output by using

```
Select * from mytable order by code asc
```

Now I want output as a Id-Id-Id.... where code is similar.
So for given snippet it should come like

```
102966-102968
102967-102969
```

So I want like that those records are similar, their code should come like this.
Please help.

Comment: Collapsing into ranges is not always a trivial thing to do. If some numbers get skipped you can't do a simple `MIN()` and `MAX()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? For example, why are `101603` and `102016` related even though they do not have the same code? If there are three or more IDs with "similar" codes, should they be displayed as ID-ID-ID-... or is it only for pairs? Should IDs which do not have a pair be excluded from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see what your last result row is about, it might be a mistake or I don't understand what you need

I think you are looking for a `group_concat`

```
select group_concat(ID ORDER BY ID SEPARATOR '-' ) AS dup
from mytable
GROUP BY code
HAvING count(*) >1
ORDER BY dup
```

Results:

```
|           dup |
|---------------|
| 102966-102968 |
| 102967-102969 |
```

A `group_concat` shows all the values matching the `GROUP BY`, here the `ID` values. 
The term `SEPARATOR` is there to specify `-` as separator between your IDs, because the default separator is `,`

If you want all rows, even those for which there are no duplicate `code`, remove the `having` clause

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/907f7/21)

Answer (score 0):

the last answer from @Thomas G is correct but if you want to have it in the correct order use:

```
select CONCAT(MIN(ID),'-',MAX(ID))
from mytable
GROUP BY code
HAvING count(*) >1
```

Comment: that works too for the given data set, but what if there are more than 2 duplicates per `code` ? Looks like it might happen as he said `Id-Id-Id` ;-)

Comment: A series of `AABBAACC` would result in A showing as 1-6 in this example, which is wrong. It should, I believe, be 1-2, 5-6. That's what makes this really complicated.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(.. ORDER BY ..)`